# SQLite3 не может найти значение в столбце!

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite3

Это функция для базы данных

```
class Panda_DataBase:
  def __init__(self, db_file):
     self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file, check_same_thread=False)
     self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

  def CheckRegistr(self, UserId):
     with self.conn:
        result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'PandaDataBase' WHERE 'UserId' = ?",(UserId,)).fetchall() 
#СРАВНИВАЕТ ВСЕ ID из базы данных с ID ЧЕЛОВЕКА
        
        print(bool(len(result))) # ВЫДАЁТ FALSE
        print(len(result)) # ВЫДАЁТ 0

        return bool(len(result))
```

Функция сверху принимает значение в виде ID пользователя.
Но почему-то когда пользователь с таким ID уже есть в БД "return bool(len(result))" всё равно выдаёт False!!
И дальше по коду добавляет его в БД(я это не вставил)

```
if not db.CheckRegistr(message.from_user.id):
    ....
```

Надеюсь понятно))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите кавычки тут `'UserId'`, т.е. чтоб было без них `UserId = ?`.

Значение в кавычках это строковый литерал, т.е. вы в условии сравниваете строку `UserId` (а не значение колонки `UserId`) с значением, которое передали в функцию. Понятно, что условие не выполняется ни для одной строки, поэтому все строки отсеиваются.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!!!